# Apply the trained caffe model and re-write the forward process

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

When I use the pre-trained VGGNet model in the caffe format, may I rewrite the forward process without changing the function of each layer?

Since I would like to re-write the forward process using the Python layer, I encounter the problem:

```
Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 22:9: Expected integer or identifier, got: "Python"
```

Does this mean I'm not allowed to modify the original prototxt or I made a mistake when writing the Python layer?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the old style prototxt is different from the current style prototxt. One is "layer" and the other is "layers".

This is a script to upgrade "V0" network prototxts to the new format.

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp